# How to set NSViewShowAlignmentRects?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/dividingResponsibility.html) about autolayout refers to setting `NSViewShowAlignmentRects` to show the alignment rects around the `UIView` objects in the app. 
I've tried setting it for Xcode, but it shows the rects for Xcode itself, not the app when it runs in the simulator.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSViewShowAlignmentRects -bool YES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES
                                        forKey:@"UIViewShowAlignmentRects"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then restart the app for it to take effect.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`?

Comment: You could also try `"UIViewShowAlignmentRects"`.

Comment: This works: 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"UIViewShowAlignmentRects"]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
You probably have to restart the app such to take effect. It works on the simulator and the device, but I lose all UI interaction (no scrolling, etc)

Comment: @noa, that works for me. Now, how to turn that off Add this code: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"UIViewShowAlignmentRects"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; And the next time you run you're having everything reversed. But how can I see those lines and still have a working app?

Comment: You should really use Xcode's launch arguments, as suggested by other answers, instead of modifying your code to write that default.

Answer (score 21):

To do this using the scheme editor in Xcode:

- In the Xcode menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme (or ⌘-<)
- In Debug, the Arguments tab, Arguments passed on launch, click the plus button and enter this:

  `-UIViewShowAlignmentRects YES` (for iOS projects)
  or
  `-NSViewShowAlignmentRects YES` (for Mac OS projects)
- You'll need the dash at the start
- Tap OK

You should have a bunch of yellow outlines when you run

[image]

Comment: I forgot the leading hyphen - that's why I arrived here :-D

Answer (score 2):

You set a simple launch argument from your app’s scheme. This is UIViewShowAlignmentRects for iOS and NSViewShowAlignmentRects for OS X. Set the argument value to YES and make sure to prefix with a dash.

http://cl.ly/image/3j3T421d0K45

Comment: Always include your image in the post. This image has expired.